# 揠苗助长 or 拔苗助长 ? Which one is correct?

Tags: idioms, chengyu

A dictionary says both chengyus being equal in meaining. Is it so, or is there any difference between these two idioms?

Comment: dictionaries agree, search web using either 揠苗助长 or 拔苗助长, result e.g.bkrs:

"揠苗助长 see 拔苗助长", users of course know that 拔 is more common than 揠

Comment: more  examples of 成语 differing  in one character but not in meaning:  http://www.wenkuxiazai.com/doc/495fe00fbcd126fff7050bf8.html

Comment: Former is classical, latter is widely-used.

Comment: 揠苗助长 is used in oral, 揠苗助长 originates from classic articles.

Answer (score 4):

Both of them are correct, they share the same meaning.

拔苗助长 is widely-used nowadays.

> 揠苗助长
>
> 基本解释：
>
> 揠：拔。
>   把苗拔起，以助其生长。比喻违反事物发展的客观规律，急于求成，反而把事情弄糟。
>
> 词语分开解释：
>
> 揠苗 : 1.见"揠苗助长"。
>   助长 : 1.帮助生长;促使增长。

http://xh.5156edu.com/html5/60564.html

Answer (score 3):

揠苗助长 is historically correct. 拔苗助长can also be understandable.

Answer (score 0):

The correct and commonly use is 拔苗助长 ( bá miáo zhù zhǎng )
[here](http://ce.linedict.com/#/cnen/entry/0f8e55729f684c9ebde8e3a486669836) is the mean of that phrase

Answer (score 0):

Both of them are correct.
"揠苗助长" is more official.

Answer (score 0):

拔苗助长 is usually colloquial expression, and 揠苗助长 is more official. Everyone knows the formmer. but less people know the latter.